# How can I store an ArrayList in SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Whats the quickest way of storing an object without using the database?

For example I want to store a List which I can go back and add or remove Hotels to/from but i don't want to create a database and all that hassle seems to be overkill.

How can i store an arraylist in shared preferences or something similarly easy?

```
public class Hotel{
  String id, name, address, phoneNumber;
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
etc
}
```

Comment: Hmm I know you do not want to hear this, but a database is all you need :D This is very powerful and not that hard.

Comment: If your app is API 11+, then you can follow @KLAL's suggestion. Otherwise: I would say you to convert your array into json and save it as string into sharedpreferences, then you read it as json and parse it again into array.

Answer (score 5):

My advice:

1. Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert any type of your object into String
2. Save that string in SharedPreferences
3. Reverse the process [using Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) to retrieve your object

Answer (score 1):

```
//Retrieve the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();
```